# using function from different module as decorator in python

Tags: python, oop, python-decorators

I have read few pages on the usage of decorators in python and was trying out few examples on how to use it. I was able to get it right when i try to have the decorator function and the orignal function all in the same script.
I am trying 2 set of codes here where i have specific intentions to be performed. Kindly help me in understanding what mistake i am making.

1.In this example, i have written by decorator function in script "dec1.py" and i am trying to import this in my second script "script.py", where i am getting TypeError "wrapper1() takes no arguments (1 given)"

```
###########dec1.py#####################
def setup (setup_funct):
    def wrapper1():
        print "******Test Section setup******"
        return setup_funct()
    return wrapper1
###########script.py################
import dec1

class setup(object):
    @dec1.setup
    def tc_setup():
        print "Configure X"
c1=setup()
c1.tc_setup()
```

2.Is it possible to have a method defined under a class to be used as a decorator function?. Here is what i am trying to run but it gives me the same TypeError "TypeError: wrapper1() takes no arguments (1 given)"

```
class Common(object):
    def setup (setup_funct):
        def wrapper1():
            print "******Test Section setup******"
            return setup_funct()
        return wrapper1

c1=Common()

@c1.setup()
def tc_setup():
    print "Configure X"


tc_setup()
```

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: Seemed like a same problem is causing the error, hence combined in one. Would appreciate if some solution is provided on this

Comment: 1) and 2) you are forgetting that normal methods receive the instance as first parameter. 2) You can but you should not do it, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967686/why-does-python-class-method-s-first-argument-change-when-used-as-decorator/65604675#65604675). Define your decorators at top-level (or in other module, top-level too) and apply to functions, classes or methods.